# float divs equal spacing with different height

Tags: jquery, css

Can we make equal spacing gap from the divs vertically and horizontally if we have different fixed height?

Please see fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/K8Qwq/

Html

```
 <div style="height:50px;"></div>
 <div style="height:60px;"></div>
 <div style="height:20px;"></div>
 <div style="height:50px;"></div>
 <div style="height:100px;"></div>
 <div style="height:20px;"></div>
 <div style="height:50px;"></div>
 <div style="height:75px;"></div>
 <div style="height:30px;"></div>
 <div style="height:60px;"></div>
 <div style="height:20px;"></div>
 <div style="height:50px;"></div>
```

CSS

```
 div{float:left; width:30%; background:red; margin:1%; }
```

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, instead, an alternative to what you are trying to achieve. If you are looking for "pinterest-style" grid system, check [jquery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). Animation, adjustable gutter (distance between each items), auto-sort and many other features. Check it out.

Comment: I think, that's a better option. Thanks Dude!

Answer (score 0):

You could cut it in three columns with a fixed width and let them float. Then each div in the column will be stick beneath each other

Answer (score 0):

Pure HTML/CSS Solution. This is just applicable if you just need 3 columns. But you can sure change the codes to make it work in any columns.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K8Qwq/1/)

**CSS**

```
.col > div {
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.col  {
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    margin:1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Changes

```
<div style="height:50px;"></div>
<div style="height:60px;"></div>
<div style="height:20px;"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div style="height:50px;"></div>
<div style="height:100px;"></div>
<div style="height:20px;"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div style="height:50px;"></div>
<div style="height:75px;"></div>
<div style="height:30px;"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div style="height:60px;"></div>
<div style="height:20px;"></div>
<div style="height:50px;"></div>
```

STYLE Changes

```
*{ margin:0; padding:0;}
div{float:left; width:30%; background:red; margin:1%; }
.clear{clear:both; width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a library you would be better organising the divs into columns which float instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/3DRwE/

```
<div class=column>
    <div style="height:50px;"></div>
    <div style="height:60px;"></div>
    <div style="height:20px;"></div>
    <div style="height:50px;"></div>
</div>
<div class=column>
    <div style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div style="height:20px;"></div>
    <div style="height:50px;"></div>
</div>
<div class=column>
    <div style="height:30px;"></div>
    <div style="height:60px;"></div>
    <div style="height:20px;"></div>
    <div style="height:50px;"></div>
</div>
```